# How do I orbit one object around another?

Tags: opengl, glut

[image]

I am trying to do animation using glut. I have 2 squares overlapping to each other and i want other square to rotate around this central object without rotating themselves. I want to rotate in orbit manner. I am calculating circular path using parametric equation and translating that one of the square to that distance. i am calling this function in a loop.

Here is my code in which the motion of other square is not in a orbit instead it moves along a diagonal of middle one. Let me know where it is going wrong.
I have added expected image as well

Comment: What exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: @AdrianMaire  the motion of other square is not in a orbit instead it moves along a diagonal of middle one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First some little tips:

1) Instead of:

```
if (i > 360) i=0;
```

Try

```
i %= 360;
```

2) glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix are useless in your code, as you apply them on the identity matrix.

3) User GL_TRIANGLES or GL_QUADS instead of GL_POLYGON

4) Avoid global variables, they cause a lot of problems.

**Solution:**

Probably a typo:

Change

```
glTranslatef(distance_x, distance_x, 0.0);
```

To

```
glTranslatef(distance_x, distance_y, 0.0);
```

Comment: how can i achieve the same effect with glRotatef() without using above manipulation?

Comment: You may use 3 manipulation:
glRotatef(i, 0.0f, 0.0f , 1.0f);
glTranslatef(0.3f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(-i, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);